# Selecting a value of a table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatable

I have a definition table, as well as two variable cells. Based on those I want to select a value from the table. See table below.

EXAMPLE

Variable cell 1 is `Fitch`, variable cell 2 is `CCC+`. I want in my output cell, called also Credit quality class, to see the value `6`. How can I do that?

TABLE

| Fitch | Moody's | S&P | Credit quality class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Aaa | AAA | 0 |
| AA+ | Aa1 | AA+ | 1 |
| BBB+ | Baa1 | BBB+ | 3 |
| CCC+ | Caa1 | CCC+ | 6 |
| RD | /LD | SD | 6 |

I tried using `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions, but I do not obtain the correct result. It does work if I use `IF` statemets for each column, but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Double Lookup

- In Microsoft 365 you can simply do:

  ```
  =IFERROR(XLOOKUP(G2,XLOOKUP(G1,A1:C1,A2:C6),D2:D6),"")
  ```
- If you don't have it, you can use `INDEX/MATCH`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(D2:D6,MATCH(G2,INDEX(A2:C6,,MATCH(G1,A1:C1,0)),0)),"")
  ```
- Either way, study the following to better understand how `INDEX/MATCH` work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=LET(step1,FILTER(A1:D6,A1:D1=B11),
INDEX(D1:D6,MATCH(B12,step1,0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use SUMPRODUCT:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$C$6=H5)*($A$1:$C$1=H4)*D2:D6)
```

This formula will work as long as variables are correct, and each variable 2 is unique in each column.